# Holomorphic covers pulling back the volume form to any integer multiple

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, differential-topology, cohomology

Let $M$ be a closed connected complex manifold with $\mathrm{dim}\:M=n$. Can there exist holomorphic covering maps $\phi_k:M\to M$ for all integers $k\geq 1$ such that $\phi_k^*:H^n(M, \mathbb{Z})\to H^n(M, \mathbb{Z})$ is multiplication by $k$?

Comment: You can't mean literal 'covering maps'.  Just take $M = \mathbb{P}^1$, which has no nontrivial covering maps of this kind.  Maybe you mean 'branched covering maps'?  Even in this case, it's not generally possible.

Comment: Elliptic curves have many maps like these; take a rectangle in the plane, identify opposite sides, and map each complex number by an integer multiple.

Comment: @RobertBryant you are correct that there no covering maps for a simply-connected manifold. But I am looking for just one example.

Comment: @BenMcKay elliptic curves do have many maps but the self-maps multiply the volume form by a square integer.

Comment: It's not true that the degrees of the self-maps of an elliptic curve are necessarily square integers; it depends on the elliptic curve. For example, for the square torus, the degree of a self-map can be the sum of any two square integers: Multiplication by a Gaussian integer $a+b\,i$ preserves the lattice of Gaussian integers $\mathbb{Z}[i]\subset\mathbb{C}$ and induces a self-map of degree $a^2+b^2$ on the square torus. More generally, for an elliptic curve that admits a complex multiplication, the degrees of its self-maps are the values of a quadratic form on an integer lattice of rank $2$.

Comment: If $M = \mathbb{C}^n/\Lambda$ where $\Lambda$ is a lattice, let $R\subset M_n(\mathbb{C})$ be the ring satisfying $R(\Lambda)\subseteq\Lambda$. Then $R$ is additively a free abelian group of rank at most $2n^2$, and $D(r) = \det_\mathbb{R}(r)$ for $r\in R$ is a nonnegative integer-valued form of degree $2n$ on $R$. Given any nonnegative integer $m$, one can choose $n$ and $\Lambda$ so that the multiplicative set $D(R)\subset\mathbb{Z}$ contains $\{1,2,\ldots, m\}$. One can even arrange that $M$ be a product of elliptic curves.  Might there be a $\Lambda$ where $D(R)$ contains $\mathbb{Z}^+$?

Comment: @RobertBryant for a complex torus, the volume form is an exterior power of the symplectic form so the determinant in question has to be a power of some integer. Isn't that right?

Comment: @vrz:  No, that is not right, at least, not a power higher than 1.

Comment: @vrz:  (This is what my actual comment above should have been; the remainder didn't post for some reason [probaby user-error].)  No, that is not right, at least, not a power higher than 1.  The point is that, for self-maps of a complex $n$-torus $M$ generated by the ring $R$ as above (when $R$ has rank larger than 1), the volume form can't necessarily be written as a higher power of a symplectic form, and, even when it can, these self-maps may not carry any symplectic form to an integer multiple of itself.